# How do you return specific information from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i am trying to pull the 'name' from the dictionary:

```
fork_fig = {'categories': [{'alias': 'burgers', 'title': 'Burgers'},
  {'alias': 'sandwiches', 'title': 'Sandwiches'},
  {'alias': 'salad', 'title': 'Salad'}],
 'name': 'Fork & Fig',}
```

i've got it to return the first letter of the 'name': 'Fork & Fig', but i cant get the entire name. this is the code i have so far:

```
def restaurant_name():
    for row in fork_fig['name']:
        return row
restaurant_name()
```

Comment: What's wrong with just `return fork_fig['name']`?

Comment: `fork_fig['name']` will return the value, you are then iterating over the value char by char and you return the first char

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: Why do you not capture the return value of `restaurant_name()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out the python documentation about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
def restaurant_name():
    for row in fork_fig['name']:
        # this loop will iterates on the letters of the name.
        return row # return the first letter and leave the function
```

To get the name you can just do this.

```
def restaurant_name():
    return fork_fig['name']:
```